# Why are there spaces between <li>'s?

Tags: html, css, margins

Why is there a space before all these `<li>`'s Please Help.

**HTML**

```
<div class="links">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="page1.html">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="page2.html">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="page3.html">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.links ul{
    display: inline;
}
.links{
    display: block;
}
.links li{
    display: inline;
}
.links a{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 290px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jy4ojyyt/

Comment: Which spaces are you referring to?

Comment: The ones between the boxes

Comment: Which browser are you using? Looks fine in Chrome to me (no spaces)

Comment: Chrome They are there.

Comment: The best and cleanest way is to clear out the HTML whitespace using `<!-- -->`.
http://jsfiddle.net/jy4ojyyt/2/

Comment: I am seeing no difference between the two fiddles posted (1st in the question & 2nd in the @RyanS answer). Which browser you are using?

Comment: @DobbyIsDead well, you may need to post a screen shot, as it appears we're not all seeing what you are.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use `Comments <!---->`

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.links ul{
    display: inline;
}
.links{
    display: block;
}
.links li{
    display: inline;
}
.links a{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 290px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
<ul>
    <li><a href="page1.html">Page 1</a></li><!--
--><li><a href="page2.html">Page 2</a></li><!--
--><li><a href="page3.html">Page 3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

parent- `font-size: 0;`
child - `font-size - XXpx`

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.links ul {
    display: inline;
}
.links {
    display: block;
    
}
.links li {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 0;
}
.links a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 290px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="page1.html">Page 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="page2.html">Page 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="page3.html">Page 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The advantage of `<!-- -->` is that you can still have multiple lines. If you only use a single line, you can just remove the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Inline-block elements render spaces between them. You can either put the li's on the same line or do some of your styling.

http://jsfiddle.net/jy4ojyyt/1/

```
<div class="links">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="page1.html">Page 1</a></li><li><a href="page2.html">Page 2</a></li><li><a href="page3.html">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: how would I do this and have the code still look nice?

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5078297/1310604